# Getting list of all users present in SharePoint Online User Profile only by using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, user-profile

Is there a possible way to list all the SharePoint Online User Profiles using PowerShell?

Need a  code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of directly querying the User Profile and then returning list of users which will be slow, we can use the Search API to get that data in a much faster way since the data will already be crawled and indexed.

Use the below commands to get that data. Here, I have used PnP PowerShell :

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/test"
Submit-PnPSearchQuery -Query "*" -SourceId "B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31" -SelectProperties "PreferredName" -RelevantResults
```

This will fetch 500 users.

Here `B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31`is the guid of the people result source. It is hard-coded and common across all tenants.

However, if the number of user profiles is `>500`, then you can use the `StartRow` parameter to get data in a paged manner.

If you want more properties, you can specify them(managed properties) in the `SelectProperties` parameter by adding them in comma-separated manner like `-SelectProperties "PreferredName,JobTitle,Department"`

References -

Download link - [PnP PowerShell](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/releases) (download the `SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline.msi` file)

[SubmitPnPSearchQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_powershell/submitpnpsearchquery)

Comment: I have tried the suggested method. But the problem is out of 317 User Profiles, only 288 are fetched. Can you tell me why the remaining are not displayed?

Comment: If you have added new accounts, it will take time to get crawled upto 1 week. Also, do check if these accounts indeed have the `PreferredName` value set. Another thing you can try is using `AccountName` and/or `WorkEmail` like `Submit-PnPSearchQuery -Query "*" -SourceId "B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31" -SelectProperties "PreferredName,AccountName,WorkEmail" -RelevantResults`